# Laravel: Creating an external row id?

Tags: mysql, laravel, race-condition

there is a table of `users` and a table of `galleries`. Each gallery belongs to a user. All records in the `galleries` table have a primary id key. I wish to keep this key internal so I exposed a `cid` (external client side id) and I increment it for each new gallery that belongs to a specific user.

The first gallery of any specific user has `cid` = 1 and the second `cid` = 2 and so on...
The problem is how to prevent race condtions while we're creating a new gallery? Let's say there are multiple people using a specific user account and creating a new gallery at the same time. How will I make sure I don't get two galleries with the same `cid`?

Answer (score 0):

What I did is:

- Search for the last record that has a `cid` and grab it's internal `id` & `cid`
- Create a new record and grab it's internal `id`
- Count records with ids between the last record and new record that belong to that user.
- Set the new `cid` to the old `cid` + count + 1